# О стульях в разных значениях

Tags: омонимы

Не очень аппетитный вопрос, но интересно, почему словом "стул" называется и то, на чем сидят, и, пардон, естественный процесс организма?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, дело в этимологии.Стул-германизм,по Фасмеру,от нем. Stuhl, готск. stols и др. (восходит к праиндоевр. *sta-lo- из* sta- «стоять»). Русск. стул - мебель из др.-русск. стулъ (грам. Ивана Грозного 1578 г.)- старое заимствование, пока до нас дошло, "обрусело", стало привычным.

В архангельском диалекте стул - «свая в фундаменте амбаров, кладовых», этимолог Тернквист рассматривает слово как особое заимств. из др.-шв. stol "стояк".Медицинский термин «иметь стул» значит то же, что «ходить на низ», т.е.сверху вниз по стояку, по кишке.

Получается, стул-мебель и стул-мед. термин оба исходят от праиндоевропейского "стоять", только второе в русском языке стало лексической калькой и ушло в диалект, а первое осталось в том значении, кот пришло в русский в древности и стало общеупотребительным.